Filtering legend items to only show one instance in an atlas or report
Trying to generate an atlas or report, and my QGIS has a layer copies in several locations.  My coverage layer/ control variable goes something like this.
I have a map item and a legend
Item 1. Variable  Layer1|Layer2|Layer3
Item 2. Variable  Layer1|Layer4

When I run the atlas/report my map turns out fine, but the legend has multiple instances of the repeated layers which I want to remove.  Ideally I think the legend should filter only to show the current variable. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?
